# Django not in other table (Not using id)

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have:

Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)                        
    myfield = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)                        

class Car(models.Model):
    categorys = models.ManyToManyField(Category)   
    myfield = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
```

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
Car.objects.filter(category__id = c.id )
           .exclude(myfield__in =                      
                    Category.objects.all()
                            .only('myfield')
                    )
           .order_by("id")
           .first()
```

I expected to find a result like this:

```
SELECT ...
 FROM `myapp_car` 
 INNER JOIN `myapp_car_categorys` 
        ON (`myapp_car`.`id` = `myapp_car_categorys`.`car_id`)    
WHERE ( ...
  AND NOT (`myapp_car`.`myfield` IN 
           (SELECT `myapp_category`.`myfield` FROM `myapp_category`))) 
ORDER BY `myapp_car`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1;
```

But i find:

```
SELECT ...
 FROM `myapp_car` 
 INNER JOIN `myapp_car_categorys` 
        ON (`myapp_car`.`id` = `myapp_car_categorys`.`car_id`)    
WHERE ( ...
  AND NOT (`myapp_car`.`myfield` IN 
           (SELECT `myapp_category`.`id` FROM `myapp_category`))) 
ORDER BY `myapp_car`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1;
```

I need use `myfield` in select, not `id`:

```
(SELECT `myapp_category`.`myfield` FROM `myapp_category`)
```

How would I get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you use `only` it will return the objects of `Category` model. So if you use it in in filtering the category objects will be used for filtering and for SQL the ids of those category objects.

If you need to filter on the `myfield` values on all the category objects, then use `values` instead:

```
....exclude(myfield__in=Category.objects.values('myfield'))
```